# Tkinter error in __getitem__ return dict.__getitem__(self, key).getObject()

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter, append, pypdf

First time coder here, I am currently programming using python to merge 4 pdfs in 2 folders. all the pdf has the same file name but prefixed. the first pdf is always prefixed with "1_", the second one "2_", the third "3_" and the fourth one is in different folder prefixed with "08_". for example [1_001.pdf, 2_001.pdf, 3_001.pdf, 08_001.pdf). Sometimes, the fourth file doesn't exist.

this is what i got so far

```
from tkinter import *
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import os

root = Tk()



# Creating a Label Widget
MainLabel = Label(root, text="PDF Rawat Jalan")
# Shoving it onto the screen
MainLabel.pack()

#Prompt Kode
KodeLabel = Label(root, text="Masukan Kode")
KodeLabel.pack()

#Input Kode

kode = Entry(root, bg="gray",)
kode.pack()
           
#define merger
merger = PdfFileMerger()

#function of Merge Button
def mergerclick(event=""):
    kode1 = kode.get()
    path_8 = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PDF\\Folder B\\"
    if os.path.exists(path_8):
        pdflocation_1 = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PDF\\Folder A\\1_" + kode1 + ".pdf"
        pdflocation_2 = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PDF\\Folder A\\2_" + kode1 + ".pdf"
        pdflocation_3 = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PDF\\Folder A\\3_" + kode1 + ".pdf"
        Output = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PDF\\output\\" + kode1 + ".pdf"
        entries = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PDF\\Folder B\\")
        filtered_entries = [file for file in entries if file.startswith("08_"+kode1)]
        file8 = str(filtered_entries[0])
        pdflocation_8 = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PDF\\Folder B\\" +file8
        merger.append(pdflocation_1)
        merger.append(pdflocation_2)
        merger.append(pdflocation_3)
        merger.append(pdflocation_8)
        merger.write(open(Output, 'wb'))
        konfirmasi = kode1 + " merged"
        testlabel = Label(root, text=konfirmasi)
        testlabel.pack()
    else:
        pdflocation_1 = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PDF\\Folder A\\1_" + kode1 + ".pdf"
        pdflocation_2 = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PDF\\Folder A\\2_" + kode1 + ".pdf"
        pdflocation_3 = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PDF\\Folder A\\3_" + kode1 + ".pdf"
        Output = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\PDF\\output\\" + kode1 + ".pdf"
        merger.append(pdflocation_1)
        merger.append(pdflocation_2)
        merger.append(pdflocation_3)
        merger.write(open(Output, 'wb'))
        konfirmasi = "file 8 not found but "+kode1 + " merged"
        testlabel = Label(root, text=konfirmasi)
        testlabel.pack()

#merger button = enter
root.bind("<Return>", mergerclick)

#Merge Button
mergerButton = Button(root, text= "Merge", command=mergerclick)
mergerButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I know the code is very messy, but it works. but only for the first time, when i put a second file name it returns the following error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\GUI.py", line 60, in mergerclick
    merger.append(pdflocation_1)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 203, in append
    self.merge(len(self.pages), fileobj, bookmark, pages, import_bookmarks)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 175, in merge
    self._associate_bookmarks_to_pages(srcpages)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\merger.py", line 448, in _associate_bookmarks_to_pages
    bp = b['/Page']
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic.py", line 516, in __getitem__
    return dict.__getitem__(self, key).getObject()
KeyError: '/Page'
```

I think this is a problem with the tkinter but i can't understand the error

Answer (score 1):

so apparently I'm supposed to put

```
merger = PdfFileMerger()
```

inside the function of the button.